# Finding $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Find  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$$

My work

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}=\frac{\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{\sqrt m}{m+1}}{\sqrt n}$$

The series 
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt m}{m+1}$$
does not converge so can I say  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$ does not exist?

Comment: Where does the upper-limit $\infty$ in the sum come from?  So you are saying $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\overbrace{1+1+\dots+1}^{n}}{n}$ does not exist?

Comment: Did you try Stolz Cesaro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The series 
>   $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt m}{m+1}$$
>   does not converge so can I say  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$ does not exist?

Because Zacky deleted his answer, I'll repeat the useful observation that divergence of a numerator does not mean the fraction necessarily diverges...

As for finding the limit; you can rewrite towards a Riemann sum:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt k}{(k+1)\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac{k+1}{\sqrt {kn}}} \tag{$\star$}$$
Now you have an upper bound:
$$(\star) : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac{k+1}{\sqrt {kn}}}\color{blue}{\le}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {\frac{k}{n}}}} = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mbox{d}x = \color{blue}{2}$$
but also a lower bound:
$$\begin{align}(\star) : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac{k+1}{\sqrt {kn}}}
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt\frac{k^2+2k+1}{{kn}}}
& \color{red}{\ge}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {\frac{k+3}{n}}}}\\
& =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=4}^{n+3}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {\frac{m}{n}}}}\\[5pt]
& = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mbox{d}x = \color{red}{2}\end{align}$$
So we have:
$$\boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n} = 2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}+\dots+\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt r}{(r+1)\sqrt n}$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{\frac rn}}{n\frac{(r+1)}{n}}$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty }\frac 1n\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{\frac rn}}{\frac rn + \frac1n}$$

$$=\int\limits_0^1\frac{\sqrt x}{dx+x}dx \approx \int\limits_0^1\frac{\sqrt x}{x}dx$$
$$=\boxed{2}$$

Comment: Am I missing something or $\frac{r+1}{n} \ne \frac{r}{n}+1$...?

Comment: I think that you have a mistake in the last expression before the integral. The denominator should be $\frac r n+\frac 1n$ and not  $\frac r n+1$.

Comment: edited...i fixed that

Comment: So $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=dx$...? You get the right answer, but it looks more like physics than mathematics :-).

Comment: This is applied mathematics 

Comment: Ah, I see... 

Answer (score 4):

By the [theorem of Cesàro-Stolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) (a discrete version of the l'Hopital rule for $\frac\infty\infty$), the quotient $\frac{\sum_{m=1}^n a_m}{\sum_{m=1}^n b_m}$ has a limit if the denominator grows to infinity and the quotient $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ of the last terms has a limit, and then both limits have the same value.

Here
$$
\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}=\frac{n+\sqrt{n(n-1)}}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 2.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know the theorem and it's a faster way to find this limit.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt m}{m+1}$$ diverges does not mean $$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{\sqrt m}{m+1}$$ does too.

For instance, the harmonic sum $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m}$ is divergent, but the sum up to $n$, i.e., $\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m}$ is a rational number.